# how to obtain color information from a point cloud and display it?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have to access the color property of a point in the point cloud using point cloud library. Any help is appreciated.

currently I am using this to display the cloud.But it is displaying only red blue green and not the actual color of the object.

```
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (
    new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer")
);

viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(cloud);
viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud, rgb, "sample cloud");
viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (
      pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE
    , 3
    , "sample cloud"
);

viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);
viewer->initCameraParameters ();
```

Comment: The code is correct, though setting a color handler is superfluous in this case. It should be sufficient to add the point cloud to the visualizer with `viewer->addPointCloud (cloud, "sample cloud");`

Comment: The cloud color is just white if i take out color handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to me okay, how do you set the color of the cloud?

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

pcl::PointXYZRGB point;

// ...

uint32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(255) << 16 |
                static_cast<uint32_t>(15) << 8 | 
                static_cast<uint32_t>(15));

point.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);

point_cloud_ptr->points.push_back(point);
```

Comment: It's possible to access color channels individually: `point.r = 255; point.g = 15; point.b = 15;`, thereby avoiding explicit shifts and cast.

Comment: which PCL version? what is the range of r/g/b? have you tried with the shift/cast method?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not tell you in which version this was introduced, but it was long ago. I remember using `r`, `g`, and `b` back in summer 2012. The range is `[0..255]`.

Comment: If you are interested, [have a look](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/common/include/pcl/impl/point_types.hpp#L219-L233) at how the `RGBA` part of point cloud structures is implemented.

Comment: that's right but if you see the reference of  [PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_point_cloud_color_handler_r_g_b_field_3_01pcl_1_1_p_c_l_point_cloud2_01_4.html) it clarifies "Uses the data present in the `rgb` or `rgba` fields as the color at each point". I'm not sure in updating `r`, `g` and `b` fields will have an impact of `rgb` or `rgba` fields.

Comment: `r`, `g`, `b`, `rgb`, and `rgba` all point to the same physical memory location because they are in [union](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Unions).

Comment: how do I use visualizer class to show the original color of an object?.